# Slow Angularjs page initialization - long delay before html loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope

I'm running an angularjs app, and can't figure out why my page is loading slowly. The css and js files all load quickly, but there is a long delay between that and when the html loads, where the app just seems to stay suspended doing nothing

[image]

headertemplate.jtml, footertemplate.html, and notelist.html are the partials being loaded to make up the view

[image]

Comment: It's maybe because you're calling external url. Please download and use local library only for font.

Comment: I thought that might be it, but removing the font doesn't change anything. The html still has that wait period

Comment: There's 1 more. Parse.serverurl. Try comment that line what is the output. Is it still same?

Comment: Nope, same behaviour unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses ajax to retrieve templates. You should be able to look at the network tab in developer tools to see the ajax request for each template. That might give you a clue as to what the hold up is.

I'm not sure why it's taking so long to receive them, but one way you can speed that up would be to pre-cache the templates with a tool like [HTML2JS](https://github.com/rquadling/grunt-html2js). This way, your templates are just another JS file that you include along with your program code and templates are loaded as soon as your program code is loaded. It will increase your initial download size, but will greatly improve the speed of fetching templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache all templates in $templateCache which will make angular app never make xhr request for partial htmls.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

There are various gulp and grunt modules to automate that process.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache
https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates

*By the way are you making any server calls in angular.forEach, for some reason they don't show up in network tab (idk why?? o.O)
Or may be you are using resolve in ui-router's state config which is taking time to activate the state and calling html partial..*